# How can I filter a table by a nested array of objects property with prisma?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma, prisma2

So I have a table with a json field, and that field has a nested field which is an array of objects. I'm trying to filter the rows by the nested array of objects to basically get rows where the nested array of object contains an object with a particular value. I keep getting 0 results. The database is PostgreSQL. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

So the table this schema:

```
model Requests {
  ...,
 properties  Json?
}
```

The format of the saved properties is like this:

```
{
   multiple: true,
   receivers: [
   {
      name: '',
      id: 1,
      status: 'Pending'
    },
    {
      name: '',
      id: 5,
      status: 'Pending'
    },
   ]
}
```

And this is my query:

```
const requests = await prisma.requests.findMany({
   where: {
        AND: [
            {
                'properties': {
                    path: ['receivers', '$[*].id'],
                    array_contains: 5,
                }
            },
            {
                'properties': {
                    path: ['receivers', '$[*].transactionStatus'],
                    array_contains: 'Pending'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, since you're using PostgreSQL and Prisma doc says:

> Filtering on object key values within an array is only supported by the MySQL

Comment: Missed that, thanks.